# jquery datatables update column by class name

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using jquery datatables in my project.I want to update a cell and this is my code

```
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{  
    oTable.fnUpdate(update_value,i,2);
}
```

Here ,I am updating third colum. 
My requirement is ,I dont want to use number for specifying column.Instead I want to use class selector.Something like

```
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{  
    oTable.fnUpdate(update_value,i,$('.columClass'));
}
```

How can I do that?.
Basically ,how to get the position of a column in datatables using class name.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{  
    oTable.fnUpdate(update_value,i,$('.columClass')[0]);
}
```